# How to add multiple instances of JSF 2 managed beans to Java Collection?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, managed-bean

I'm trying to wrap my head around some basic JSF 2 concepts. For instance, if I have a managed bean, Bean1:

```
@ManagedBean
public class Bean1 {
    private String foo;
    private String bar;
}
```

and the values for `foo` and `bar` are obtained from a JSF web form. On each submit of the web form, I want to store an instance of `Bean1` in a Java Collection of another bean:

```
@ManagedBean
public class Bean2 {
    private List<Bean1> beanList;
}
```

What is the correct way to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `Bean2` a managed property of `Bean1` so that you have access to its `beanList` property.

```
@ManagedBean
public class Bean1 {
    private String foo;
    private String bar;

    @ManagedProperty("#{bean2}")
    private Bean2 bean2;

    public void submit() {
        bean2.getBeanList().add(this);
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

*(please note that this way just the reference is stored, not a clone of the `Bean1`'s state or something!)*

Needless to say that this is a design smell. There are likely better ways to achieve the concrete functional requirement which you've had in mind while asking the question but didn't tell anything about. In the future try to ask how to solve the functional requirement instead of how to achieve a solution (which may not be the right solution after all).

Comment: Thanks, BalusC! I'll keep in mind your advice about asking for concrete help on requirements in the future.

Answer (score 4):

BalusC is 100% per cent right, but (as he warns) his answer will be useless. The important point here is that you do not need nor want the second bean to be managed at all. It is your model, not your GUI. You probably wanted something like:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
class PeopleHolder {
    private List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();

    // not managed at all:
    private Person currentPerson;

    // just the getter, no need for a setter
    public Person getCurrentPerson() { return currentPerson; }

    @PostConstruct
    public init(){ currentPerson = new Person(); }

    public void addCurrentPersonToList() {
        people.add(currentPerson);
        init();
    }

    // just for test:
    public List<People> getPeople() { return people; }
}
```

and now a form:

```
<h:form>
   <h:inputText value="#{peopleHolder.currentPerson.name}" />
   <h:inputText value="#{peopleHolder.currentPerson.lastName}" />

   <h:commandButton action="#{peopleHolder.addCurrentPersonToList}" />
</h:form>
```

Comment: I think you hit the nail on the head as to what the OP *really* needed :)